# Invalid patch path /requestTemplates/ for AWS API Gateway Body Mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am following [this tutorial](https://sanderknape.com/2017/10/creating-a-serverless-api-using-aws-api-gateway-and-dynamodb/) to set up API to dynamoDB through AWS API Gateway.

According to the instruction, was to body map to this code

```
{
  "TableName": "favorite_movies",
  "Key": {
    "name": {
      "S": "$input.params('name')"
    }
  }
}
```

However, I received this error ( Invalid patch path */requestTemplates/*)
May anyone help me, please.
Thanks in Advance.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What ended up being the solution?

Comment: I had the same error.  In my case reloading the page eventually fixed it.  I think it happened because I clicked the check mark with the content type field empty, then later I filled in the correct value.

But, I had some weirdness after that.  I think it's some kind of bug.

Comment: @RD1 Thanks for this trick, it's helped. Obviously, it's not expected behavior.

Answer (score 9):

Content type needs to filled as "application/json" which is corresponding to the model specified.

Ideally, specifying model name should be enough as that has the content type as well.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error. Try reloading it and it should work then.